# max-height in ie8-compatibility mode

Tags: css, xhtml, height, ie8-compatibility-mode

For some reasons (richfaces 3.3.3) I have to use the ie-compatibility mode for ie8 in ie:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8,IE=8" />
```

I use in my xhtml this selectManyCheckbox:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="artManyCheckbox" value="#{dokumenteUebersicht.dokumentArtFilter}" layout="pageDirection" style="overflow-y:auto; display:block; max-height:125px;">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{dokumenteUebersicht.dokumentArtSI}" />
                                    <a4j:support id="artAllFields" event="onclick" actionListener="#{dokumenteUebersicht.reload}" reRender="dokumente" />
                                </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

and it works for chrome and firefox fine. Only IE (9 or 11) which runs in IE8-Compatibility Mode ignores the max-height.I read some posts here about posttype problems, so I took a look in the developer tools:

```
<!--DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" -->
```

IE is commenting out my doctype declaration. I am not sure that this is maybe only a presentation problem from the developer tools and has nothing to do with my max-height problem. In chrome the doctype declaration in the developer tool is not commented out.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't tell IE to not use IE 8 compat instead of use it? Like, what the hell kind of draconian boss is forcing you to design something specifically for an EoL'd browser, yet wanting to support modern ones like Chrome?

Comment: The problem is richfaces 3.3.3, it is only running good in IE 9 and IE 11 with IE8-compatibilitiy-mode. I have to migrate to Primefaces one day and most of my problems will be gone, but it is a 500 xhtml sites application, so this will take a long time. Until that happens I have to live with the situation and fix the small things as good as I can.